# Spring Boot annotation @GetMapping can not be resolved to a type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

I tried creating a Spring Project from Spring Initializr for the first time in my local computer. But I am getting these errors @GetMapping cannot be resolved to a type.

My pom.xml file-

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can someone help me with this? Is there some dependency I am missing?

Comment: `@GetMapping` is in `spring-web` which you are already depending upon. In fact, you are depending on it more than once as both it and `spring-webmvc` are dependencies of `spring-boot-starter-web`. I would guess that Maven has corrupted the `spring-web` jar when it downloaded it. Try deleting it from Maven's cache and rebuilding your application.

Comment: Likely a corrupted maven download, try running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` or go and delete the `.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web` folder and update or compile your maven project again

Comment: Hello @DarrenForsythe . I tried deleting the the spring-web dependency from the maven repository manually. And rebuilt the project. But the error still persists.

Comment: Hello @AndyWilkinson I tried rebuilding the project after deleting the jar. But the error is still there. This is my first spring project.

Comment: Can you share the code that's using `@GetMapping`? Perhaps you're missing an import statement or the package is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You have all dependenices which required for spring boot to run and I used your same pom and its worked, few points:

1. If you have

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

then not required:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

</dependency>
```

you can delete these dependencies as starter includes it.

2. Also add maven plugin

   ```
   <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   ```

and after this from command line: run mvn clean install
3. then try to rebuild project
4. if still do not work then move your starter-web as first dependency and again check.

Comment: I tried all the things you mentioned. But the error still persits.

Comment: I having the same issue. **@GetMapping** isn't resolved. I tried this solution, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Under file -> Invalidate caches->check(Clear file system cache and Local History, Cleared downloaded shared indexes)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hITgd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start with https://start.spring.io/ for Spring Initalizr project. You're missing this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't think this'll help. The question says that Spring Initializr was used and `spring-boot-starter` is already being used as it's a dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web`. Even if it wasn't, depending on `spring-boot-starter` wouldn't fix the problem as `@GetMapping` is part of `spring-boot-starter-web`.