# Cannot resolve @GetMapping in Spring tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a spring project in Spring tool Suite.

Even after adding all dependencies it shows cannot resolve @GetMapping

**Error Message**

```
GetMapping cannot be resolved to a type
```

My code is

```
package tacos;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    @GetMapping
    public String home()
    {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

As you can see in this line I have already imported GetMapping.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>Taco cloud example</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**I have already tried solution provided in this post**

[Spring Boot annotation @GetMapping can not be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190102/spring-boot-annotation-getmapping-can-not-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you never include Spring MVC to your project , hence it cannot resolve the classes come from it.

You should include `spring-boot-starter-web` in `pom.xml` which will transitively get the Spring MVC and an embedded Tomcat for you :

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It worked. But Now there is a yellow line under saying The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping is never used. @KenChan

Comment: yellow line is a just warning , you could ignore it

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195083/taven-at-stackoverflow @KenChan

Comment: @KenChan You have imported GetMapping twice. Press `Ctrl+Shift+O` to automatically fix the imports.

Comment: @helospark . Thanks for the tips 